# How to convert a color (in RGB mode) to transparent color for PNG using C#?

Tags: c#, png, jpeg

I will be converting a jpg to png and than I wish to remove an RGB color with values (254,242,211) to a transparent color in PNG using C#. Can anyone point me to a good tutorial and/or code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to do folowing:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(_jpegFilePath);
bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.FromArgb(254,242,211));
bmp.Save(_pngFilePath);
```

Should work.

Regards.

Comment: To save as png you should `bmp.Save(_pngFilePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)`

Comment: accoridn to documentation seems that it's default image format.

Comment: Could you please provide a link of that documentation, also note that you are here creating `Bitmap` object from a `jpeg` file, so when you save it will save as the `jpeg` file format.

Comment: @Jatal: it is actully in regard if Image.Save method:                            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah.aspx                            "If no encoder exists for the file format of the image, the Portable Network Graphics (PNG) encoder is used"

Comment: PNG is the default, regardless where it came from.

Comment: @Hans: what do you mean precisely?

Comment: I think @Hans mean regardless the original image file format "Comment on `also note that you are here creating Bitmap object from a jpeg file, so when you save it will save as the jpeg file format`"

Comment: @Tigran I'm getting a  `'System.Drawing.Color' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments`   error on the line `bmp.MakeTransparent(new Color(254,242,211));` why is that?

Comment: Sorry @John, writing from mobile, so no coding tool on hands. I updates my post, please have a look.